# Can I get help getting my map to be a fixed position?

Tags: css

I would like my map to be on a fixed position on the screen so that when the user scrolls the map is still on the same spot. Here's what I've got:

```css
#map {
    float: right;
    height: 545px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 30px; 
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to post your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `top` and `right` properties. Not float or margins.

```css
#map {
        height: 545px;
        width: 40%;
        top: 12px;
        right: 30px; 
        position: fixed;
        background:red;
    }
 #cont {background:rgb(2,0,36);background:radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,121,103,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);;height:1000px}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="map"></map>
</div>
```